# Issue reading from XML file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I need to get the following value from the XML file.

```
<container>
  <name>ServerName</name>
  <type>Node1</type>
  <applications>
    <application Name="App1">
      <Attribute1>A</Attribute1>
      <Attribute2>B</Attribute2>
    </application>
    <application Name="App2">
      <Attribute1>C</Attribute1>
      <Attribute2>D</Attribute2>
    </application>
    <application Name="App3">
      <Attribute1>E</Attribute1>
      <Attribute2>F</Attribute2>
    </application>
  </applications>
</container>
```

In order to get App3 Attribute1 I found the following XPATH expression: 
`/container/applications/application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1`

The problem is that I don't know how to use the above xpath expression in Powershell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to get Attribute1 from App3:

```
 Select-Xml -Content $Xml -XPath "//applications/application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
```

output:

> E

Comment: Nicely done; note that, as an alternative to passing the XML _string_ via `-Content`, `Select-Xml` can accept _file paths_ directly, via parameters `-Path` and `-LiteralPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xml] document to search for the required element in xml.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\Temp\new.txt
$value = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//container//application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1").InnerText
# $value => E
```

`XPath` that you use inside `SelectSingleNode` can be set up based on your need. `//container//application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1` means

- Look for the tag container 'anywhere' in the document
- Look for application anywhere under the container tag
- Look for Attribute for application that equals App3
- Under that specific Attribute tag, (if there is one), find Attribute1 and get the innerText.

You can also write the above statement in this way as well. This means that find application tag "anywhere" in the document but it has to have Name attribute equals to App3.

```
$value = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1").InnerText
```

Comment: Nice, though I would use the query from the question as-is in the first snippet, given that it is an absolute path to the target element (no need for `//`). With small files it won't matter, but it's more efficient to use `Get-Content -Raw`  to read the entire file as a single string when casting to `[xml]`. @Eudin, note that the `Select-Xml` solution in the other answer is an equally valid one and simplifies the file-parsing part.

Comment: @mklement0 regarding the parsing, file-parsing is still required for the other solution as well (you have to pass in $xml). Also, given that the html provided could be within a document, I suggested the approach of // so it covers that scenario

Comment: @Jawad: In the specific solution, yes, the XML text is passed as a _string_, but `Select-Xml` can accept _file paths_ directly (`-Path`, `-LiteralPath` parameters). It's fine if you don't want to assume that `container` is the _root_ element of the XML document (though the question suggests that the sample is the _full_ document), but then I suggest using `//container/applications/application[@Name='App3']/Attribute1`. The `//` approach is covered by your 2nd snippet.